# Getting data from HTML or JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, http

Let's say I have a HTML table with 5k rows and 50 columns (generated from JavaScript object) and I would like to send 50 checked rows (checkbox) from client to server using HTTP (JSON). What would be more efficient? Iterating in HTML to find the checked rows or iterating trough my JavaScript object to find corresponding rows?

> fields = columns (50)
>
> values = rows (~5k)

**JavaScript data object:**

```
parent {
  child: [{field1: value1, field2: value2, field3: value3, and so on...}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this information, but interacting with the DOM is one of the slowest things you can do, so you should check the JavaScript objects.

Comment: This answer helps me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While you generate each row, you keep a reference of the checkbox and you bind it to your data in a javascript object.

Then you add an event listener on the checkboxes: when you tick on or off a row, you push or remove the mapped data line in an array that will always be up to date and ready to be sent.

Comment: Should I fetch the 'line' from HTML or from JavaScript object?

Comment: If I were you, while I generate each row, i'll keep a reference of the checkbox mapped on the data managed by it in a javascript object. That way, when a checkbox is ticked or unticked, you can easily see which data should be sent or not!